# Get last 10 days stats php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I try to get stats from signup on my website.
To get stats, I use this function :

```
 public function get_stats_10_days_signup()
    {
        try
        {
            $data_stat = Array();
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT DAY(added) as DisplayDay , COALESCE(COUNT( added ), 0) as DisplayUsers FROM users WHERE  added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  GROUP BY DAY( added )");
            $stmt->execute();
            $message = '';

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                // do loop stuff
                $message .= '[';
                $message .= $row['DisplayDay'];
                $message .= ', '.$row['DisplayUsers'];
                $message .= '],';
            }
            return $message;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

But, the result is :

```
Day             Signup
2017-03-17      2
2017-03-20      4
2017-03-23      1
```

And what I want, when there is no record, that indicate 0 because I want to use these datas on a chart:

```
Day             Signup
    2017-03-17      2
    2017-03-18      0
    2017-03-19      0
    2017-03-20      4
    2017-03-21      0
    2017-03-22      0
    2017-03-23      1
```

Comment: have you tried using **COUNT(added)** or **COUNT(*)** instead of **COALESCE(COUNT(added), 0)** ?

Comment: Yes I tried this method too but not working